# substr me aparece con una línea en el centro, ¿hice algo mal?

Tags: javascript

Desearía saber el motivo por el cual el método `substr` aparece con una lineal en el centro y los demás no, ¿algo pasa con `substr`? muestro mi código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función `substr` está obsoleta y se recomienda no usarla. Si bien ahora te puede funcionar en cualquier minuto la retirarán completamente ("el que avisa no es traidor"). Mas información [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

Por ende, tu editor te está alertando de esta situación

En su lugar, puedes usar [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```js
let str = "holasoy una palabra";

console.log(str.substring(1, 3));
console.log(str.substr(1, 3));
```

OJO! El segundo parámetro de ambas funciones significan cosas distintas:

Para:

- **substr**: Determina la cantidad de elementos
- **substring**: Es el índice del primer carácter que se va a excluir de la subcadena devuelta. En otras palabras, es el índice del siguiente al último incluido